# What do the axis labels mean in this plot (apparently from Sutton 8th edition)?

Tags: mathematics, rocket-equation

In the Analytical Graphics Inc. video [Low-Thrust Space Trajectory Design and Optimization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3H39PMUVtE) the speaker Pradipto Ghosh of AGI shows a slide at around `07:00` shown below.

On it there is a plot with the vertical axis labeled $\Delta u / v_c$ and the horizontal axis labeled $v/v_c$.

What do the variables used in these axis labels represent?

Any other explanation of how the plot should be interpreted or used is appreciated!

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Paul Thanks! I wonder if that's almost a complete answer, and worth posting as such? These are normalized with respect to $v_c$, if you can find out what $v_c$ is then you're probably good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caption in the book (Sutton) reads:

> Normalized vehicle velocity increment as a function of normalized exhaust velocity for various payload fractions with negligible inert mass of propellant tanks. The optima of each curve are connected by a line that represents Eq. 17–9.

The text reads:

> For a given mission, theoretically there is an optimum range of specific impulse that maximizes $\Delta u / v_c$ and thus a most favorable propulsion system design.
>
> ...This characteristic speed ($v_c$) does not represent a physical quantity but rather a grouping of parameters that has units of speed; it can be thought of as the speed a power plant’s inert mass $m_{pp}$ would attain if its full power output were converted into kinetic energy.